# function use cases of str.join

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
>>> print "-".join(chr(2)*5)    
'\x02-\x02-\x02-\x02-\x02'    
>>> print "-".join(chr(2) for _ in xrange(5))   
'\x02-\x02-\x02-\x02-\x02'
```

What is the difference between the two?

I don't understand the execution sequence of `"-".join(chr(2) for _ in xrange(5))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the definition of `join` function:

```
str.join(iterable)

Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the iterable iterable.
```

In the first case your iterable is `chr(2)` which is repeated 5 times.
In the second case the iterable is

```
chr(2) for _ in xrange(5)
```

where `xrange(5)` is expanded to the sequence `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)`, 
and `_` is an arbitrary variable (it could be `i`, `x` or anything else).

So, in both cases you have `chr(2)` repeated 5 times.

Answer (score 2):

`str.join` takes an iterable, which both `chr(2)*5` and `chr(2) for _ in xrange(5)` are.

You can see it by doing this

```
>>> list(chr(2) for _ in xrange(5)) == list(chr(2) * 5)
True
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first example repeats the string 5 times and join using dash as delimiter. As you can see `chr(2)*5` returns a string.

```
>>> type(chr(2)*5)
<type 'str'>
```

The second example join a generator using the same delimiter.

```
>>> type(chr(2) for _ in xrange(5))
<type 'generator'>
```

Also string and generator are both instance of [iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable) and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) returns the concatenation of the strings.

```
>>> from collections import Iterable
>>> isinstance(chr(2)*5, Iterable)
True
>>> isinstance((chr(2) for _ in xrange(5)), Iterable)
True
```